# How to pass Model from a view to a partial view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that is **not** strongly typed. However I have in this view a partial view that is strongly typed.

How do I do I pass the model to this strongly typed view?

I tried something like

```
 public ActionResult Test()
        {
              MyData = new Data();
              MyData.One = 1;
              return View("Test",MyData)
        }
```

In my TestView

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("PartialView",Model); %>
```

This give me a stackoverflow exception. So I am not sure how to pass it on. Of course I don't want to make the test view strongly typed if possible as what happens if I had like 10 strongly typed partial views in that view I would need like some sort of wrapper.

Comment: you're right about the wrapper, and its not a bad way to go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should extend your model so that it can provide all necessary fields for the view (this is called ViewModel) or you provide them seperately with ViewData.

```
 public ActionResult Test()
        {
              MyData = new Data();
              MyData.One = 1;
              ViewData["someData"]=MyData;
              return View();
        }
```

then:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("PartialView",ViewData["someData"]); %>
```

ViewData is a nice losely typed dictionary

Comment: What do you mean?If your partial view is strongly-typed with the MyData class, line above will render your view without a problem. As you can see, you send more than one models into your view by ViewData because it is not strongly typed, then you pull your models for each strongly-typed PartialView.

Comment: I tried this but doesn't work for me so I tried @Html.Partial and found that works for me. I don't know why is it though.

Answer (score 0):

Put the object required by the partial into Viewdata and use ist in the view as input for the partial.

```
public ActionResult Test()
        {
              ViewData["DataForPartial"] = new PartialDataObject();
              return View("Test")
        }
```

In the view use:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("PartialView",ViewData["DataForPartial"]); %>
```

But anyway: There is no reason no to have a stronly typed view.

Comment: The problem is not it being the view being a strongly typed view is the fact that if you have more then one partial view in that view you can't make it a strongly typed view to fit all those cases unless you make some sort of wrapper or I guess use ViewData.